# Libgdx change screens and player position

Tags: java, libgdx

I have two screens created how the libgdx tutorial shows me. When I enter a certain area of one screen, the next loads with no problem and vice versa. What my issue is is trying to get the player to be loaded at a certain spot after the new screen loads.

```
  Game.setScreen(some screen())
  Dispose();
  Player.setX(50);
```

This is what I tried and it doesn't work. The screen doesn't load and just puts the player at the specified position.

Would I need to destroy and create a whole new player object for this to work?

Comment: Do you just need to add the player to the new screen and remove him from the old one? It's hard to tell what's going on because you have nearly no code. (*also, there are multiple libgdx tutorials so I don't know which you are trying to follow*)

Comment: need more code. Usually my player object would exist within screen not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The player exists only in the screen you are using in the beginning? Then you need to handover it over to the new screen.

I'd also appreciate to see a bit more of your source code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like EvilBurrito said, your player only exists in your first screen. So you need to create a new one in the second screen.

But you can also put your player object in another class (maybe your main class). You can use your player in the 2 screens by getting the player object from that upper class.